Postgres function to compute Bowley seven-number-summary
I have a number of data sets which I'm trying to get a seven figure summary for (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-number_summary#Bowley%E2%80%99s_seven-figure_summary for background)
It's pretty trivial to get each of the various numbers (min, max, first and third quartiles, first and last deciles and median) from a single result set.
However, if I want to get it off various stats, I find myself dealing with a lot more redundant code than there should be.
For example:
create table example (x integer, y integer, z interval);

insert into example values
    (1,2,'1 min'),
    (3,10,'20 seconds'),
    (3,40,'3 seconds'),
    (2,1,'3 minutes'),
    (10,10,'1 hour');

select percentile_disc(0) within group(order by value) as minimum,
    percentile_disc(0.10) within group(order by value) as first_decile,
    percentile_disc(0.25) within group(order by value) as first_quartile,
    percentile_disc(0.5) within group(order by value) as median,
    percentile_disc(0.75) within group(order by value) as third_quartile,
    percentile_disc(0.9) within group(order by value) as last_decile,
    percentile_disc(1) within group(order by value)
from (
    select x as value from example
) data;

select percentile_disc(0) within group(order by value) as minimum,
    percentile_disc(0.10) within group(order by value) as first_decile,
    percentile_disc(0.25) within group(order by value) as first_quartile,
    percentile_disc(0.5) within group(order by value) as median,
    percentile_disc(0.75) within group(order by value) as third_quartile,
    percentile_disc(0.9) within group(order by value) as last_decile,
    percentile_disc(1) within group(order by value)
from (
    select y as value from example
) data;

select percentile_disc(0) within group(order by value) as minimum,
    percentile_disc(0.10) within group(order by value) as first_decile,
    percentile_disc(0.25) within group(order by value) as first_quartile,
    percentile_disc(0.5) within group(order by value) as median,
    percentile_disc(0.75) within group(order by value) as third_quartile,
    percentile_disc(0.9) within group(order by value) as last_decile,
    percentile_disc(1) within group(order by value)
from (
    select z as value from example
) data;

When run, this gives me:
postgres=# \i ~/cc/bowley-example.sql
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 5
 minimum | first_decile | first_quartile | median | third_quartile | last_decile | percentile_disc 
---------+--------------+----------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------
       1 |            1 |              2 |      3 |              3 |          10 |              10
(1 row)

 minimum | first_decile | first_quartile | median | third_quartile | last_decile | percentile_disc 
---------+--------------+----------------+--------+----------------+-------------+-----------------
       1 |            1 |              2 |     10 |             10 |          40 |              40
(1 row)

 minimum  | first_decile | first_quartile |  median  | third_quartile | last_decile | percentile_disc 
----------+--------------+----------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------
 00:00:03 | 00:00:03     | 00:00:20       | 00:01:00 | 00:03:00       | 01:00:00    | 01:00:00
(1 row)

postgres=#

This is fine as output but all but one of those lines in each of the three queries is identical. Code duplication being a nasty small, I feel like there has to be a neater solution.
Note that the real data sets I'm working with have a few extra criteria, which I've omitted in the interest of simplicity:

They're much bigger so performance is a consideration.
I'm also intending on using first (see https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate) ) to get the best and worst examples in certain cases.
There's multiple tables with varying types
I'm intending in using this in different places so I'm really after a function I can apply as opposed to a combined result (i.e. these being different types and different results is a desirable)


Keep in mind readability for others may be more useful than optimal code.  Sometimes you de-normalize your data for performance.  Code can have a similar need for readability; keep in mind potential future maintenance needs.

@xQbert Not entirely sure I get your point. I'm looking to trim out the code duplication here - that should make it more readable, surely?

You can get all three rows wih one query if you convert your intervals into integer (seconds) so all of the columnns in all rows are of the same type. You will need to prepare your data with a recursive cte (or any other way), though:
WITH    -- recursive cte (data) to get all values in the same column
  RECURSIVE data (id, axis, val) As
    ( Select   1, d.axis, d.val
      From   ( select 1 as id, 'x' as axis, x as val from example Union All
               select 2, 'y', y from example Union All
               select 3, 'z', Cast(EXTRACT(epoch From z) as integer) from example 
             ) d
      Where    d.id = id
    Union All
      Select   id + 1, axis, val
      From     data
      Where    id + 1 < 2
   )

--    M a i n    S Q L :      (just a bit changed, but essentialy your code)
Select      percentile_disc(0) within group(order by value) as minimum,
            percentile_disc(0.10) within group(order by value) as first_decile,
            percentile_disc(0.25) within group(order by value) as first_quartile,
            percentile_disc(0.5) within group(order by value) as median,
            percentile_disc(0.75) within group(order by value) as third_quartile,
            percentile_disc(0.9) within group(order by value) as last_decile,
            percentile_disc(1) within group(order by value), 
            Case When axis = 'z' Then 'z (seconds)' Else axis End as axis
From      ( Select axis, val as value From data ) data
Group By    data.axis;

/*    R e s u l t :
minimum first_decile    first_quartile  median  third_quartile  last_decile percentile_disc  axis
------- --------------  --------------  ------  --------------  ----------- ---------------  ---------------
      1              1               2       3               3           10              10  x
      1              1               2      10              10           40              40  y
      3              3              20      60             180         3600            3600  z (seconds)    */

See the fiddle here.

Thanks for this. Doesn't quite do what I want. Updated question to clarify.
